# How to fix src attribute in script tag

Tags: javascript

This is my code in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="run">Hello World</button>
</body>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

And this is my file index.js code, which is in the same folder:

```
function run() {
    console.log('Example');
    alert()
}
```

My problem is, the button won't reach the function run(),  it's not recognising it. I also tried doing run() on the onclick="" And still didnt work.

Comment: And the question/problem is? -> [mcve]

Comment: Two problems: 1. It's `onclick="run()"`, 2. The function has to be available before the element that uses it (or even better don't you inline JS at all and instead use `.addEventListener()`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the onclick function call as below.

```js
function run() {
    console.log('Example');
    alert('Test')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="run();">Hello World</button>
</body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the code does not run is because you forgot to include `()` after the function name.

If you instead write your button like this it will work:

```
<button onclick="run()">Hello World</button>
```

While I'm at it, I might also suggest at least moving the `script` tag to the bottom of the `body` tag, instead of having it outside. Alternatively, you could write `<script defer src="...` and put it in the `<head>` tag